# Error when trying to load tables from desktop with dashDB

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm trying to load a csv file into a table and receiving the following error:
[image: Dash DB Error]

The steps that I am doing are launching the dashDB instance that I have, Load, Load from Desktop, Browse for the csv... I have tried to create a new table from the csv and add to an existing table, both resulting with the error. I have also created a dummy csv with just 1 record in it and it is also failing with the same error. When creating the table from the load, the result is the table getting created with no data loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is an already known bug of the Bluemix Dashboard integration with the dashDB one: 
The team is working on this issue, but a fully working workaround is available.

In order to complete your data loading through your file you should:

- access your application section on the Bluemix dashboard
- click on the 'Environment variables' section and select the 'VCAP_SERVICE' button
- retrieve the 'https_url' of the dashDB service and save also the related username and password values
- paste on your browser url the https_url value, it will open directly the dashDB dashboard, you can now login using the username and password found in VCAP_SERVICE section
- click on 'Load' section in the left menu of the dashDB dashboard
- in this section you could upload your file without any problem.